# itext lock some fields after sign - one field ok but second field sign cause error?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, acrofields

so i want to check if itext (version 8) is good for me needs

i need to add sign fields and based on them lock some other fields in acro form,

so i have it like :

```cs
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("AddSignFieldItext77.pdf");
            iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);

            var newPage = pdf.AddNewPage(new PageSize(PageSize.A4));
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

            var formRectangle = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(100, 800, 200, 20);
            var formFieldBuilder = new TextFormFieldBuilder(pdf, "TextFormField1");
            formFieldBuilder.SetPage(newPage);
    
            formFieldBuilder.SetWidgetRectangle(formRectangle);
            var formfield = formFieldBuilder.CreateText();
            form.AddField(formfield);

            var formRectangle2 = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(100, 700, 200, 20);
            var formFieldBuilder2 = new TextFormFieldBuilder(pdf, "TextFormField2");
            formFieldBuilder2.SetPage(newPage);

            formFieldBuilder2.SetWidgetRectangle(formRectangle2);
            var formfield2 = formFieldBuilder2.CreateText();
            form.AddField(formfield2);

           
            var signatureRectangle1 = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(36, 448, 200, 100);
            var signatureField1 = new SignatureFormFieldBuilder(pdf, "SignField1");
            signatureField1.SetPage(newPage);
            signatureField1.SetWidgetRectangle(signatureRectangle1);
            PdfSignatureFormField sig1 = signatureField1.CreateSignature();
            

            PdfSigFieldLock pdfSigFieldLock1 = new PdfSigFieldLock();          
            string[] fieldToLock1 = new string[] { "TextFormField1" };
            pdfSigFieldLock1.SetFieldLock(PdfSigFieldLock.LockAction.INCLUDE, fieldToLock1);         
            PdfDictionary dict = sig1.GetPdfObject();
            dict.Put(PdfName.Lock,pdfSigFieldLock1.GetPdfObject());
            form.AddField(sig1);


            var signatureRectangle2 = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(36, 248, 200, 100);
            var signatureField2 = new SignatureFormFieldBuilder(pdf, "SignField2");
            signatureField2.SetPage(newPage);
            signatureField2.SetWidgetRectangle(signatureRectangle2);
            PdfSignatureFormField sig2 = signatureField2.CreateSignature();

            PdfSigFieldLock pdfSigFieldLock2 = new PdfSigFieldLock();         
            string[] fieldToLock2 = new string[] { "TextFormField2", };
            pdfSigFieldLock2.SetFieldLock(PdfSigFieldLock.LockAction.INCLUDE,fieldToLock2 );
            PdfDictionary dict2 = sig2.GetPdfObject();
            dict2.Put(PdfName.Lock, pdfSigFieldLock2.GetPdfObject());
            form.AddField(sig2);
            pdf.Close();
```

and this works almost fine - produces pdf like this

[image]

And i can sign 1st field. it is fine. saved , signed , `TextFormField1` locked.

And then if i want sign second field - i get error as on screenshot that function parrameter had an incorrect value?

[image]

If i **close and re-open document - i can sign in this `SignField2` without error**
but i do not want to have to close and re-open doc for second sign

please advice how to fix this - am i missing something here? is there better approach?

best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, Adobe Acrobat (at least the version 2023.001.20174 I use currently) runs into an issue when you try to sign both signature fields in a single session.

At first inspection no errors in the PDF could be identified. Thus, I created a similar file using Adobe Acrobat itself and observed that Adobe Acrobat does not run into the same issue with that. Then I determined the differences and tried to find out which differences are relevant.

As it turns out, there is only one relevant difference: If the signature field dictionaries have a correct **Type** entry, Adobe Acrobat can sign both PDF signature fields in a single session. iText, on the other hand, does not add a **Type** entry by default.

As the **Type** entry is specified as *optional* and as there is only one allowed value for it in case of signature field dictionaries, this clearly can be considered an Adobe Acrobat bug.

As a work-around you can add the type explicitly using iText like this:

```c#
...
PdfSigFieldLock pdfSigFieldLock1 = new PdfSigFieldLock();
string[] fieldToLock1 = new string[] { "TextFormField1" };
pdfSigFieldLock1.SetFieldLock(PdfSigFieldLock.LockAction.INCLUDE, fieldToLock1);
PdfDictionary dict = sig1.GetPdfObject();
dict.Put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.Annot); // <-----
dict.Put(PdfName.Lock, pdfSigFieldLock1.GetPdfObject());
form.AddField(sig1);
...
PdfSigFieldLock pdfSigFieldLock2 = new PdfSigFieldLock();
string[] fieldToLock2 = new string[] { "TextFormField2", };
pdfSigFieldLock2.SetFieldLock(PdfSigFieldLock.LockAction.INCLUDE, fieldToLock2);
PdfDictionary dict2 = sig2.GetPdfObject();
dict2.Put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.Annot); // <-----
dict2.Put(PdfName.Lock, pdfSigFieldLock2.GetPdfObject());
form.AddField(sig2);
...
```

Comment: it was that - thanks a lot . do You think i should open feature request on itext or something? maybe in such a case it should add it by default - as we se here is more important than anyone thought so ;)

Comment: *"You think i should open feature request on itext or something?"* - I already left a hint with them. But a second voice might give the issue more weight... Actually, though, you also might want to tell Adobe - this after all essentially is an Acrobat bug.

Comment: ok i will send adobe link to this topic :) ragards !